# Hidden Methods in Java?

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java on my own, and this question has been puzzling me for a while, even though I'm sure the answer is a simple one. I was wondering whether there are hidden methods obtained through extending certain classes, such that you can call the method in the subclass without referencing super.method(... ? For example, take a look at this ButtonPanel class:

```
class ButtonPanels extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ButtonPanels(){
        JButton yellow = new JButton("Yellow");
        JButton blue = new JButton("Blue");
        JButton red = new JButton("Red");

        add(yellow);
        add(blue);
        add(red);
    }
}
```

The "add" methods here... where do they come from? It seems that writing super.add works perfectly fine, which confuses me. Don't you need to write super in front of all methods you call from a superclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not "hidden" methods. The `super.` is optional when calling a method from the superclass (as long as you haven't overridden it in your own class, then you need `super.` to distinguish it from your own implementation).

The [documentation for `JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) lists all these methods under the "Method Summary" header, specifically in the "Methods inherited from class java.awt.Container" section (there are multiple overloads of `add` which is why it is mentioned more than once there).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write `super`. If the method definition is not available in this class, jvm checks for the method availability in super class.

`super` is required, if you have overrriden method and would like to call `super` class implementation instead of `sub` class implementation (overriden implementation)

Comment: So, if you were overriding the superclass method with a method of a similar name, but you wanted to call the superclass method, would you then need to write super?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, otherwise, overriden implementation will be invoked.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess I was confused because the only time I had read about super methods was when I saw an example of overriding a superclass method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect of polymorphism. The ButtonPanels class is both a ButtonsPanel and JPanel. As such it has access to most of the methods in JPanel as if they are in ButtonsPanel itself. The super becomes important if you overload a method that exists in the super class.

In your case, super.add(Object j) and add(Object j) are exactly the same when you call them because add is not overloaded.

To add, polymorphism is the concept that an object can take multiple forms. It is itself and all super classes at the same time and can referenced as such. In the case of this button panel all the below are different ways to construct the object.

```
JButton j = new JButton();
Container c= new JButton();
Object o = new JButton();
```

(Its late and I hope I don't have these backwards, someone please let me know if I do)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

JVM/Compiler is smart enough to check the availability of method. It check if the method is available in current class. If it is , it uses the one available. If not , it checks the super class. If available there it uses it. If not it goes one more level up till it finds the implementation. The compiler gives error about method not found if it do not find it any class.